# Get an existing session in my BaseController constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-controller

In my Global.asax, i have this code in the Session_Start() :

```
UserIntranet user = new UserIntranet();
user.Login = this.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
Session["user"] = user as UserIntranet;
```

In my BaseController, i have this property :

```
public UserIntranet UserIntranet
{
    get 
    {
       return Session["user"] as UserIntranet; 
    }
}
```

It's working in all of mines controllers who use this base controller but not in my BaseController Constructor himself.

This session is Null...

Have try this in my BaseController :

```
public BaseController()
{
    ViewBag.UserMenu = this.UserIntranet.Login;/* Null */
}
```

Why? How can i get the user login directly in my BaseController? What is the better way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's normal, all `HttpContext` related objects such as the `Session` are not yet initialized in the constructor of an ASP.NET MVC controller. This happens at a later stage, in the [`Initialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method that you could use:

```
public BaseController: Controller
{
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        ViewBag.UserMenu = this.UserIntranet.Login;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Override the method? But how can i get this existing session? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Sure, I have updated my answer with an example. Don't try to use the Session in the constructor of the controller, you should override the `Initialize` method and you could use the session in there.

Comment: You're my hero :) Thanks a lot !